# NHibernate.QueryException: not an association: Id

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

I wrote a joint query using NHiberNate, but I am getting a NHibernate.QueryException:not an association: Id

This is what it looks like with NHibernate library

```
TicketRequest ticketAlias = null;
        Show showAlias = null;

        IList<TicketRequest> results = UnitOfWork.CurrentSession.QueryOver<TicketRequest>(() => ticketAlias)
                  .JoinAlias(() => ticketAlias.ShowId, () => showAlias.Id)
                  .Where(() => showAlias.ShowDate >=DateTime.Now)
                  .List();

        return results;
```

I just want a simple joint statement, and this is what it would have been in SQL

```
select * from TicketRequest as a join Show as b
on a.Show_id = b.Id
where ShowDate >=GETDATE()
```

Can someone help and let me know why I am getting a "not an association:Id" error. I have id in the "Show" table, it is a primary key.

Please advise. All helps are greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you please post you model or Hibernate table mapping class?

Comment: I am going to pull the source code on my PC and then I will post here.

Comment: This is the Mapping class for TicketRequest

Comment: @user2510115                                                            namespace MarilynDenisServices.Core.FluentMapping
{
    public class TicketRequestMap : ClassMap<TicketRequest>
    {
        public TicketRequestMap()
        {
            Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Native().UnsavedValue("0");

   Map(x => x.Name).Not.Nullable();

   Map(x => x.StreetAddress).Not.Nullable();

   Map(x => x.City).Not.Nullable();
   
   Map(x => x.CancelationDate);
   
   Map(x => x.ShowID);
   References(x => x.Show);
   }
   }

Comment: @user2510115 this is the mapping for Show class <pre><code>namespace MarilynDenisServices.Core.FluentMapping

    public class ShowMap : ClassMap<Show>
    {
        public ShowMap()
        {
            Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Native().UnsavedValue("0");

   Map(x => x.ShowDate).Unique().Not.Nullable();

   
   Map(x => x.Notes).Length(10000);
   
   Map(x => x.TicketedSeats).Not.Nullable();
   
   Map(x => x.ModifiedDate).Not.Nullable();
   
   HasMany(x => x.TicketRequests).Inverse().Cascade.DeleteOrphan();
  }
    }
}</pre></code>

Comment: @user2510115 as you can see, my TicketRequestMap class has a show id. And in the SQL table, this show id is the same as the id in table Show. So are you saying , I should be adding an association in my code ? If so, what is the right way to do it in NHibernate? I am a Nhinberate noob...sorry

Comment: Please edit your question to include the mapping. Code is very hard to read in comments.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify a many-to-one relation in joins. In your case that is the `Show` property.

```
IList<TicketRequest> results = UnitOfWork.CurrentSession.QueryOver<TicketRequest>(() => ticketAlias)
    .JoinAlias(() => ticketAlias.Show, () => showAlias)
    .Where(() => showAlias.ShowDate >= DateTime.Now)
    .List();
```

PS: You shouldn't map both a many-to-one relation (`Show`) and an foreign key property (`ShowID`). Usually you only work with object relations when using an ORM. Only map the plain ID if you really need it for something, but even then only map it as read-only.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to specify the foreign keys / primary keys when querying with NHibernate. It's an ORM. You write object oriented queries. The keys and relations are specified in the mapping file.

A Join in an NHibernate query is simply specified by the property name with which you navigate to the other property.

That's what the error message means. `Id` is not an association.